# Object sharing and dynamic instance creation

Tags: c#

I've a base class for business logic operations that is being inherited by my co-worker. This class expose a constructor which requires an `objectContext` as parameter. You can think of this base class as a component for atomic CRUD operations (all its select, insert, edit and delete method will always act on just one entity).

Then, I have a "super class" which its primary purpose is shared the `objectContext` between all the above base class in order to execute some business transaction and also it must provide any `baseClass` instance, if required.

So, I'm looking for to elegant way to "inject" superClass's `objectContext` into a `baseclass`:

```
public BaseClass<T> where T : entity
{
    private ObjectContext _ctx;
    public BaseClass(ObjectContext ctx){ _ctx = ctx;}
    public virtual IList<T> Select(){..}
    public cirtual voind Insert(T entity){..}
    // other stuff 
}

public class SuperClass
{
    private ObjectContext _ctx = new...
    public BaseClass<TEntity> LoadBaseClass(TBase, TEntity) where TBase : BaseClass<TEntity>, where TEntity : class
    {
        BaseClass<TEntity> obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TBase), _ctx); // share objectContext
    }
    public int SaveAll(){return _ctx.SaveChanges();}
}
```

As you can see, my super class is able to return some `baseClass` instance through its type and it's just what I want. However, if some inherited class defines its own contructor with other parameter my `LoadBaseClass` method will fails.

I would find a clean solution in order to avoid any kind of possibility of error during instance creations from `LoadBaseClass` method. The only way I know is to define a private contructor, but by this way no-one will be able to inherit `baseclass` anymore..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). You are now trying to build this by hand but there are a lot of tools that already do what you want.

Dependency Injection is all about constructing objects and configuring how and when those objects are created. It comes down to splitting object creation from your business logic.

In your case, you are working with something called the [Unit Of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) and [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) pattern. Using a Dependency Injection container like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) you can easily configure your `UnitOfWork` to be shared between all repositories like this:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IMyRepository>().To<ConcreteRepository();
kernel.Bind<IMyUnitOfWork>().To<ObjectContextImp>().InRequestScope();

IMyRepository repos = kernel.Get<IMyRepository>();
```

What Ninject (or any DI tool) will do is try to construct a `IMyRepository`. You've configured it to look for a `ConcreteRepository`. Then it notices that the `ConcreteRepository` takes a `IMyUnitOfWork` in its constructor. In this case you have mapped this to your `ObjectContextIml` and added the `InRequestScope` option.

`InRequestScope` is for ASP.NET web applications and it means that your context should be created once for each request. Ninject has a couple of different [Object Scopes](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) that you can use to configure how your object should be created and shared.

This way, you have complete control over how your objects are created.

Comment: It's impossibile to accomplish for my app. My app is a bit more complex how can you imagine.. I work with multiple objectContex on different database and I want let co-worker free to build UnitOfWork and business classes how can they prefer.

Comment: Dependency Injection is used for all sorts of applications but mostly in the more complex applications. With your current solution you are trying to build something that Dependency Injection containers have already done for you. I would strongly encourage you to read some of the DI documentation to really make sure that it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Sure, DI could be a good solution for many scenario, but I think it cannot fit to my case. I would remeber you that ObjectContext is not necessarily shared beteween businessClass. In fact BL class can live by itself. Sharing needs only depend by my co-worker builds their logic. What I want to do is offer a "base" component for atomic crud and transaction operations.

Comment: What about a protected instead of a private constructor?

Comment: A protected CTOR implies a sort of Method injector and I'm not crazy for this..but it just seems the only solution I can use. The best way should be to allow superclass only to instantiate BusinessClass through CTOR.